# How to add custom columns to a WinForms DataGrid (CAUTION: Not DataGridView)

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

I have a program that contains a DataSet with two DataTables and one DataRelation. This way I can show all records from a "parent" DataTable, and user can expand one of this records to see all its "children".

Code to create DataTables, DataRelation and display DataGrid is as follows:

```
DataSet dataSet;        

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataSet = new DataSet();

    CreateParentsTable();

    CreateSonsTable();

    dataGrid1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"];
} //Form1

//Function to generate parents table and fill it with random records
private void CreateParentsTable()
{
    dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable() { TableName = "parentsTable" });

    dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "ID" });
    dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Name" });
    dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Sex" });

    //Generation of 101 random records
    for (int i = 100; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        int randomSeed = DateTime.Now.Millisecond * i;

        Random r = new Random(randomSeed);

        DataRow row = dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"].NewRow();

        row.SetField<int>("ID", i);
        row.SetField<string>("Name", GenerateRandomString(randomSeed, 4));
        row.SetField<string>("Sex", r.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? "Men" : "Women");

        dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"].Rows.Add(row);
    } //for
} //CreateFathersTable

//Function to generate sons table and fill it with random records
//This function will also generate relation between fathers and sons tables
private void CreateSonsTable()
{
    dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable() { TableName = "sonsTable" });

    dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "ID" });
    dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Name" });
    dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Sex" });
    dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "ParentID" });

    dataSet.Relations.Add("Display sons",
        dataSet.Tables["parentsTable"].Columns["ID"],
        dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Columns["ParentID"]);

    dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Columns.Add("Parent", typeof(string), "Parent.Name");

    //Generation of 301 random records
    for (int i = 1000; i <= 1300; i++)
    {
        int randomSeed = DateTime.Now.Millisecond * i;

        Random r = new Random(randomSeed);

        DataRow fila = dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].NewRow();

        fila.SetField<int>("ID", i);
        fila.SetField<string>("Name", GenerateRandomString(randomSeed, 8));
        fila.SetField<string>("Sex", r.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? "Boy" : "Girl");
        fila.SetField<int>("ParentID", r.Next(100, 201));

        dataSet.Tables["sonsTable"].Rows.Add(fila);
    } //for
} //CreateSonsTable

//Function to generate a random string of a specified size
private static string GenerateRandomString(int seed, int size)
{
    char[] characters = new char[size];

    Random r = new Random(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        characters[i] = Convert.ToChar(r.Next('A', 'Z' + 1));
    } //for

    string randomString = new string(characters);

    return randomString;
} //GenerateRandomString
```

Very important thing to keep in mind: I'M USING A DATAGRID, NOT A DATAGRIDVIEW.

Now, this makes the DataGrid display all columns in the DataTable. But maybe I would like to show only some columns (for example, it makes no sense to show "fatherID" column in child table). I would also like to define some columns as other control rather than TextBox (CheckBoxColumn for booleans, ComboBoxColumn for foreign keys...).

It's all this possible using DataGrid?

Comment: Why the restriction on DataGridView? Either way you can set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and then manually add the columns to the DataGrid for only the columns you want to show.

Comment: The restriction on DataGrid is simply because with DataGridView I can't find any way of doing what I want. Basically I want to have a table with all parents, and when user expands a parent all children of that parent appear (kind of like a TreeView). And I can't add columns to DataGrid because dataGrid1.Columns doesn't even exist